# Use react-input-mask with antd without getFieldDecorator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm new to React and I would like to use `react-input-mask` with `antd` input field. If I use `getFieldDecorator` and `Form.create`, everything works.

In inputmask.js:

```
const CustomInput = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <ReactInputMask {...props}>
      {inputProps => (
        <Input
          {...inputProps}
          ref={ref}
          disabled={props.disabled ? props.disabled : null}
        />
      )}
    </ReactInputMask>
  );
});

CustomInput.propTypes = {
  mask: PropTypes.string,
  maskChar: PropTypes.string,
  formatChars: PropTypes.object,
  alwaysShowMask: PropTypes.bool,
  inputRef: PropTypes.func
};

export default CustomInput;
```

In index.js:

```
function FormBuilder(props) {
  const { getFieldDecorator } = props.form;

  return (
    <Form>
      <Form.Item label="Phone">
        {getFieldDecorator("phone", {
          rules: [{ required: true, message: "Phone is required." }]
        })(
          <CustomInput
            mask="+7 (999) 999-99-99"
            placeholder="+7 (___) ___-__-__"
          />
        )}
      </Form.Item>
      <Button htmlType="submit" type="primary">
        Send
      </Button>
    </Form>
  );
}

const App = Form.create({ name: "form" })(FormBuilder);
```

Here is [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-input-mask-wantd-final-dkp8o?fontsize=14).

But if I delete `getFieldDecorator` and `Form.create` (as I will use `react-final-form` and I won't need them), the mask doesn't work.

Here are my new index.js and [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-input-mask-wantd-final-8ihln?fontsize=14).

```
function App(props) {
  return (
    <Form>
      <Form.Item label="Phone">
        <CustomInput
            mask="+7 (999) 999-99-99"
            placeholder="+7 (___) ___-__-__"
          />
      </Form.Item>
      <Button htmlType="submit" type="primary">
        Send
      </Button>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

The code is basically the same, but in the second example, the mask is not working. Could you please tell me, where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getFieldDecorator` API](https://ant.design/components/form/#this.props.form.getFieldDecorator(id,-options)) manages it's form fields `value`s **for you**.

In case you remove it, you need to manage it by yourself.

You can assure it by rendering only `CustomInput` and it still won't work as you were aspected.

```js
function FormBuilder(props) {
  // Won't work
  return (
    <CustomInput mask="+7 (999) 999-99-99" placeholder="+7 (___) ___-__-__" />
  );
}
```

To fix it, as mentioned above, **manage the input state by yourself**, [for example](https://codesandbox.io/s/q-57131583-inputmask-4syvu):

```js
function App(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  return (
    <Form>
      <Form.Item label="Phone">
        <CustomInput
          value={value}
          onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
          mask="+7 (999) 999-99-99"
          placeholder="+7 (___) ___-__-__"
        />
      </Form.Item>
      <Button htmlType="submit" type="primary">
        Send
      </Button>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Q-57131583-InputMask]

> **Notes:**
>
> 1. if you using other `form` library like [`react-final-form`](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form) don't mix components, like using `Form.Item` of antd inside `Form` of
>      `react-final-form`, **use a single library** or you will get
>      unexpected results.
> 2. antd `Form` is an implementation of [`rc-form`](https://github.com/fis-components/rc-form) so you can use its extended api.
> 3. When you using a **complete UI-library** like `antd` **you need a very good reason** to use other components, rethink if you really need
>      other `form` library.

Comment: 1) Yes, I know. 2) Thank you. 3) I probably need some adviсe here. I wanted to use `react-final-form` because I have a complicated form with steps, some custom elements, conditional input fields and some reusable parts like address or personal data for different people. I know you can do it with `react-final-form`. Is it possible to do this with native form in `antd`?

Comment: You need to compare the API's, the properties you describe are not a special thing for a form library and antd supports them.